# How to make a Unity-style event manager for C# / .net?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, events

I'm a big fan of Unity's event manager pattern, described here: https://john-tucker.medium.com/discovering-unity-eventmanager-a040285d0690

Using this pattern, any object anywhere in the program can start listening to, stop listening to, or trigger an event by name (a string).

I'm working on a C# native .net project and I really want to do something similar. But I keep hitting obstacle after obstacle. C# doesn't have a UnityEvent class that works the same way, so I haven't been able to translate the code directly. C# typically recommends using a delegate / event system, but in those cases the event must be triggered manually on the object that declares it (instead of being triggered by name from anywhere).

I am 100% certain there is a way to do this in C# without too much difficulty but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried looking at both the observer / listener pattern and the mediator pattern, but have not been able to use those successfully.

Would really appreciate any assistance or advice. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just use e.g. a `Dictionary<string, Action>`, everytime someone adds a new listener you either add a new item or extend the action. Then you can just Invoke these when needed ...

Comment: @derHugo could you show me an example of how you would trigger or subscribe to an event using a Dictionary<string, action>? It seems that this solution would allow us to hold a reference to the callback by name - I think what I want is a reference to the event by name? I've tried working it out several ways but keeping hitting walls.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. It probably isn't great but it works.

```
        Dictionary<string, List<Action<CustomObject>>> customObjectActionList;

        public void AddListener(string eventName, Action<CustomObject> callback) {
            List<Action<CustomObject>> thisEvent = null;
            if (!customObjectActionList.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
            {
                customObjectActionList.Add(eventName, new List<Action<CustomObject>>());
            }
            customObjectActionList[eventName].Add(callback);
        }

        public void RemoveListener(string eventName, Action<Player> callback) {
            playerEventList[eventName]?.Remove(callback);
        }

        public void TriggerEvent(string eventName, CustomObject obj) {
            List<Action<CustomObject>> thisEvent = null;
            if (customObjectActionList.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisList))
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < thisList.Count; n++) {
                    thisList[n].Invoke(obj);
                }
            }
        }

        //Create new dictionary, AddListener method, Trigger method, and RemoveListener method for each custom object or data type
```

Comment: You don't really need lists .. as said an `Action` should be enough see e.g. [how do I combine several Action<T> into a single Action<T> in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559807/how-do-i-combine-several-actiont-into-a-single-actiont-in-c)